# Duda sobre CamelCase - CodeWars - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estuve haciendo un ejercicio en WWW.codewars.com con python que consistía en que el usuario ingresara algunas palabras separadas por guiones("-" o "_") y yo lo que tenia que hacer era que devolviera las palabras con la convención "camelCase. Dejo el ejercicio de la pagina por las dudas. https://www.codewars.com/kata/517abf86da9663f1d2000003/python.
Un ejemplo a lo que hay que hacer: "the-stealth-warrior" tiene que ser convertido a "theStealthWarrior"

---

Dentro de mi código con el for recorro cada indice para agregarlo a la variable "palabras". El problema esta en que a la hora de testear con las palabras "A-Cat_is_Omoshiroi" me devuelve: "ACatIsOmoshro" y deberia ser: "ACatIsOmoshiroi". (se que probablemente no sea la mejor forma de resolver la actividad pero de todas formas quiero encontrar cual es el problema)

```
def to_camel_case(text):                                                       
palabras = ""
k = 0
for i in text:                                                                                                               
    if i != "-" and i != "_" :  
        print(i)                                           
        if text[text.find(i) - 1] == "_" or text[text.find(i) - 1] =="-":  
            j = text.find(i, k)
            pass
        else:
            palabras += i                                                 
            j = text.find(i, k)                                               
    else:                                                                  
        palabras += text[text.find(i, j) + 1].upper()                      
    k += 1
return palabras
```

Básicamente en mi código hice que vaya agregando cada letra a la variable "palabras", si lo que habia e el índice era algún tipo de guion agregaba la letra siguiente en la posición que en todos los casos seria la letra que quiero que sea mayúscula, la convertía, y cuando volvía a recorrer el bucle en la posición de la que debería ser mayúscula si en el índice anterior había un guion, salteo la letra. Espero que se haya entendido.

Comment: Yo diría que codewarriors es como dar un examen, y pedir ayuda para buscar soluciones es como copiar en un examen. El problema es que el puntaje que obtenga no reflejara tus reales capacidades como programar.

Comment: Lo se, ya pedi la solucion en codewars, el tema esta en que no encuentro el problema en mi codigo, la solcuion al ejercicio ya la tengo. pero no veo porque el for no me devuelve dos letras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un problema de lógica en el código. Para mirar si la letra anterior a la actual es un guión, cuando la letra actual está almacenada en la variable `i`, haces:

```
 if text[text.find(i) - 1] == "_" or text[text.find(i) - 1] =="-":
```

Si esa condición se cumple actualizas `j`, pero no metes esa letra en la palabra resultante. Si en cambio la condición no se cumple, entonces sí metes esa letra en la palabra resultante.

El problema que tienes es que esa condición no está realmente mirando la letra anterior a la actual, pues `text.find(i)` no te devuelve la posición de la letra actual, sino la posición en que **aparece por primera vez** una letra igual a la actual.

Esto se ve mejor sobre tu propio caso de ejemplo: "A-Cat_is_Omoshiroi"

Fíjate en qué ocurre en la última iteración del bucle. En esa última iteración la letra es una `"i"`. Esta letra es el valor de la variable `i` (vaya, coincide el nombre de la variable con su contenido, ¡lo siento!). El caso es que `text.find(i)`, que en este caso sería `text.find("i")` encontrará la primera "i" en el texto. Esa primera `i` resulta ser la de "is". Y esa primera "i" sí que tiene un "_" delante, por lo que según tu algoritmo, no se añade al resultado. Por eso desaparece.

La solución es no usar `text.find()` para averiguar cuál es el índice de la letra que estás procesando, sino llevar aparte un contador con el índice. Una forma sencilla de lograrlo es usar `enumerate(text)` que te irá devolviendo parejas de valores `indice, letra`.

Al eliminar la necesidad de `find()`, eliminamos también la necesidad de `j` (pues su valor será el del `indice`) y la necesidad de `k`.

Usando esa estrategia y sin tocar para nada el resto de la estructura de tu código, la cosa quedaría así:

```
def to_camel_case(text):                                                       
  palabras = ""
  for indice, i in enumerate(text):                                                                                                               
      if i != "-" and i != "_" :  
          print(i)                                           
          if indice>0  and text[indice - 1] == "_" or text[indice - 1]  == "-":  
              pass
          else:
              palabras += i                                                 
      else:
          palabras += text[indice + 1].upper()                      
  return palabras
```

Una vez vemos así el código, resulta también bastante claro que hemos complicado la lógica más de lo necesario. En realidad cuando el carácter sea distinto de "-" o "*", lo que haremos es bien copiar la letra en cuestión tal cual (si el anterior no era "*" ni "-") o bien copiarla pasándola a mayúsculas (si el anterio era "_" o "-"). Por tanto podemos sustituir el `pass` por la copia mayúscula, eliminando así el `text[indice+1].upper()` que es confuso.

La nueva versión sería por tanto:

```
def to_camel_case(text):                                                       
  palabras = ""
  for indice, i in enumerate(text):                                                                                                               
      if i != "-" and i != "_" :  
          if indice>0  and text[indice - 1] == "_" or text[indice - 1]  == "-":  
              palabras += i.upper()
          else:
              palabras += i                                                                     
  return palabras
```

Aún podrían hacerse mejoras que reducirían el código y mejorarían su legibilidad, pero este no era el objetivo de la pregunta, en la que solo se preguntaba por qué la solución "se comía" algunas letras.

Comment: Ahora entiendo cual era el problema, me sirvio bastante tu aporte, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder!